# Treating the output of a plot function as a graphics object, changing the opacity

Tags: plotting, graphics

I want to treat the output of a plot (DensityPlot specifically) as a single graphics object and reduce its opacity. Something like:

```
DensityPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction -> 
"SunsetColors", Frame -> False,MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #3 &}, 
Mesh -> 10] //  Graphics[#, Opacity[.1]] &
```

except this actually doesn't work...

Comment: If the `DensityPlot` is called `plot`, then: `plot /. Graphics[a_, b___] :> Graphics[{Opacity[0.1], a}, b]`.

Comment: Actually, even better: `DensityPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
 ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", Frame -> False, 
 BaseStyle -> Opacity[0.1]]`

Comment: What is the intended application? Do you mean you want the output to have `Head` of `Graphics`, or be a graphics object of the kind that goes *inside* a `Graphics`?

Comment: g1 = DensityPlot...
    g1 /. Graphics[a_, b___] :> Graphics[{Opacity[0.1], a}, b]
This didn't actually change the opacity of anything...

    BaseStyle -> Opacity[0.1]
This helped---it did change the opacity of the colored patches but doesn't change the opacity of the mesh. (I forgot to include the fact that I have "MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #3 &}, Mesh -> 10" included in my Options for Density plot, so it looks a lot like a ContourPlot.)

Comment: @Jens: Intended application? I want to make a GraphicsRow of some 2D basis functions. I want to "weight" their contribution to an eigenfunction by their opacity. So the plots that don't contribute at all with have an opacity of 0

Comment: If the plot is produced as described, `plot/. GrayLevel[__] -> Opacity[n]` where *plot, n* are symbol of plot and desired opacity is a QND way to get it done.

Comment: @ciao That works sort of, but then it makes the mesh lines too dark for values near `Opacity[1]` (i.e., darker than they were in the original).

Comment: @ciao If this didn't have the problem Jens points out, it would be perfect. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is that the plot already included `Opacity` directives when mesh lines are drawn, so that one would have to change their opacity using a replacement rule, separately from the opacity of the gradient.

Instead, I would suggest achieving the same effect by just putting a blank `Inset` *on top* of your plots, with an opacity that varies in the opposite direction as what you want to see of you plot:

```
d = DensityPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, 
   ColorFunction -> "SunsetColors", Frame -> False, 
   MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #3 &}, Mesh -> 10, ImageSize -> 200, 
   AspectRatio -> 1];

With[{bgColor = White},
 GraphicsGrid[Table[
    Show[d, 
     Epilog -> 
      Inset["", Automatic, Automatic, Scaled[1], 
       Background -> Directive[Opacity[i], bgColor]]], {i, 0, 1, .1}]~
   Partition~2]]
```

[image: opacity]

Here, I gave the `Inset` a background of the same color as the paper (`White`). The last argument of `Inset` is used to expand it to the size of the enclosing plot. For more control, I also decided to add `ImageSize` and `AspectRatio` specifications to the plot `d`.

Comment: I suppose there'll be some side effect? when you overlap a image with opacity over another, the other image will show up, while in your solution, it won't. Are there anyway to solve this problem? still, a great answer!

Comment: Jens, this a great answer. I still wish there was a way to "convert" the whole plot, mesh lines and all, to a graphics object of some sort. That way I could control the opacity just like it was a Circle[], or Rectangle[]. I'm making 16 of this as little thumbnails for use in a GraphicsRow. Wish I could alter them the same way that I can alter a graphics primitive.

Comment: I suppose one could export the plot as a image, import it, and then change the opacity via BaseStyle:

    g = Import["ExampleData/rose.gif"]
    Show[g, BaseStyle -> Opacity[.1]]


Maybe there's a way to convert it to an image without exporting it first... (Sorry I can figure out how to format comments. My code is all squashed together and not highlighted like code...)

Answer (score 1):

OK, this solution is less sophisticated than Jens' answer and some of the suggestions in the comments, but maybe it will be of use to someone else. I want to treat the entire plot (frame, legends, everything, if they exist) as single entity and adjust its opacity. So I turn it all into an image first and then adjust the opacity of the image. Brute force, but maybe a good solution for my context.

```
g1 = DensityPlot[x^2 - y^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, ColorFunction ->,
"SunsetColors", Frame -> False, MeshFunctions -> {#3 &, #3 &}, Mesh -> 10]
i1 = Image[g1]
Show[i1, BaseStyle -> Opacity[.3]]
```

[image]

Comment: If you really must: `SetAlphaChannel[Rasterize[g1], 0.3]`.

Comment: @ J.M. Even better. Thanks